# HTTP Status 500 - Failed to load application class error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I am creating Vaadin 6 application using eclipse Kepler. Tomcat Server is main page running (localhost:8080). But when I run an application, I get HTTP Status 500 - Failed to load application class error.

```
type Exception report

message Failed to load application class: com.example.secondone.SecondoneApplication

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.example.secondone.SecondoneApplication
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I'm using Vaadin 6.8.13 and have installed the plugins and added the jar to WEB-INF --> lib folder.

I'm not able to figure out the exact cause of this error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

These types of errors are usually caused by issues in the project configuration. Make sure you haven't made any typos in your `web.xml` and systematically check your project structure for any  mistakes. Could it be, for example, that your application class is actually named `SecondOneApplication` instead of `SecondoneApplication`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now, I am getting HTTP Status 404 error. The requested resource is not available. Apache tomcat server is running and welcome page also comes. I dont know what is going wrong in configuration.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 error was due to problem in jar file. Now, again I get HTTP Status 500 - Failed to load application class error. Application class name is fine. What are the other possibilities of this kind of error.

Comment: Look at the log files of your tomcat. Usually you see why it is failing

Answer (score 0):

Its application is trying to run this class is:

```
com.example.secondone.SecondoneApplication
```

But she is not lying. Somewhere in your configuration files you must is by setting this package. Try other variations like:

```
secondone.SecondoneApplication
```

Or just :

```
SecondoneApplication
```

If you were using Hobernate, it would be in the archives:

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

and its mapping:

```
secondoneapplication.hbm.xml
```